# How to efficiently change names of arguments in R

Tags: r, maps

My code shows a map in different states using this code:

```
library(maps)
map("state", c("Virginia", "Maryland"), interior = FALSE)
map("state", boundary = FALSE, col="black", add = TRUE)
```

I want to change the c("Virginia", "Maryland) to work with a variable I made, state = c('VA', 'MD') so that I can change which states are displayed later in the code. Is there a way to make it so c(state) could replace the c("Virginia", "Maryland") besides the brute force way of saying

```
if (state == 'VA') state = Virginia
if (state == 'MD') state = Maryland
#and so on
```

so I don't have to write lines of code for each state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are built in vectors for state names and abbreviations. If you have

```
state = c('VA', 'MD')
```

you can get the names with

```
state.name[match(state, state.abb)]
# [1] "Virginia" "Maryland"
```

Comment: Your code worked well. I just had to change it to state  = state.name[match(state,state.abb)] because for some reason it was just giving me all 50 states otherwise

Answer (score 2):

If there weren't built-in lists (I did this before reading the other answer :-), you could scrape all the abbreviations easily, so you don't need to code it up yourself.  Then make a list of keys to values

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://state.1keydata.com/state-abbreviations.php"
abbrevs <- readHTMLTable(url)[[2]]
key <- with(abbrevs[2:nrow(abbrevs),],
            setNames(as.character(unlist(abbrevs[2:nrow(abbrevs),c(1,3)])),
                     as.character(unlist(abbrevs[2:nrow(abbrevs),c(2,4)]))))
head(key)
# AL           AK           AZ           AR           CA           CO 
# "Alabama"     "Alaska"    "Arizona"   "Arkansas" "California"   "Colorado" 

state <- c("VA", "MD")
key[state]
#         VA         MD 
# "Virginia" "Maryland"
```